# Есть задачи в которых LocationManager лучше FusedLocation?

Tags: android, gps, геолокация

`LocationManager` устарел и о нем следует забыть или он в каких то функционалах превосходит `FusedLocation`?

Например для GPS-трекера и точного отслеживания автомобиля `FusedLocation` можно использовать или `LocationManager` использовать предпочтительней?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется что FusedLocation предпочтительнее, зато использование LocationManager не требует зависимоcти от Google Play Service(а ведь есть немало китайских девайсов на которых не установлены Google Play сервисы)

Comment: Спасибо, за отзывчивость, это интересный ответ)